# Converting indentation into parentheses

Tags: sed

I'm trying to write a `sed` script to convert indentation into equivalent parentheses.

For example, parentheses should be placed in this

```
A
    A1
        A1a
    A2

B
    B1
```

such that it looks like this

```
(A
    (A1
        (A1a))
    (A2))

(B
    (B1))
```

or maybe this (once the parentheses are placed the whitespace doesn't matter anymore):

```
( A ( A1 ( A1a ) ) ( A2 ) )
( B ( B1 ) )
```

Assuming for simplicity that

1. there is only one token on each line,
2. indentation happens by tabs,

the principle seems straightforward:

1. add an opening parenthesis before the token if its indentation depth is higher than that of the previous line;
2. count the number of tabs the current line has more than the next, add 1 and put that many closing parentheses after the token.

However, teaching `sed` that the change of one line depends on how another line looks doesn't seem straightforward to me.

Comment: @Cyrus thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Cyrus nope. I probably should have created the second example by removing the newlines from the first instead of typing it out from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think sed is up to this. Not in a readable and maintainable way anyhow.

Here's GNU awk:

```
$ cat file
A
    A1
        A1a
    A2
    A3
B
    B1
        B1a
            B1aa
C

$ gawk '
      BEGIN { prev=-1 }
      {
          match($0, /^(\t*)(.*)/, a)
          level = length(a[1])
          close_parens = (level <= prev) ? prev - level + 1 : 0
          for (i=1; i<= close_parens; i++) printf ")"
          printf "\n%s(%s", a[1], a[2]
          prev = level
      }
      END {for (i=0; i<= level; i++) printf ")"; print ""}
  ' file

(A
    (A1
        (A1a))
    (A2)
    (A3))
(B
    (B1
        (B1a
            (B1aa))))
(C)
```

Comment: Okay. Though it puts parentheses on empty lines when it shouldn't (my bad for not putting one in the example).